Memory-efficient attention forward operator error in Docker container with FastAPI and DINOv2
I'm currently working on an API using FastAPI to serve DINOv2 models from the official DINOv2 repository. The API works well locally, but when I run it in a Docker container, I encounter an error related to the memory-efficient attention forward operator.
API.py
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile, HTTPException, Form
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse
import torch
from PIL import Image, UnidentifiedImageError
from torchvision import transforms
import io
import requests  # Import the requests library
import logging

# Configure logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

app = FastAPI()

# Dictionary to map model names to their respective identifiers
MODEL_MAP = {
    'dinov2_vitl14': 'dinov2_vitl14',
    'dinov2_vits14': 'dinov2_vits14',
    'dinov2_vitb14': 'dinov2_vitb14',
    'dinov2_vitg14': 'dinov2_vitg14',
}

# Load the model based on the provided model name
def load_model(model_name: str):
    if model_name not in MODEL_MAP:
        raise ValueError(f"Model {model_name} is not supported.")
    model = torch.hub.load('facebookresearch/dinov2', MODEL_MAP[model_name])
    model.eval()
    return model

# Preprocess the image
def preprocess_image(image):
    input_image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image)).convert('RGB')
    preprocess = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.Resize(256),
        transforms.CenterCrop(224),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225]),
    ])
    input_tensor = preprocess(input_image)
    input_batch = input_tensor.unsqueeze(0)  # Create a mini-batch as expected by the model
    return input_batch

# Perform inference
def infer(model, input_batch):
    with torch.no_grad():
        output = model(input_batch)
    return output

@app.post("/infer/")
async def infer_image(file: UploadFile = File(...), model_name: str = Form(...)):
    try:
        if model_name not in MODEL_MAP:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Invalid model name provided.")

        image_bytes = await file.read()
        input_batch = preprocess_image(image_bytes)
        model = load_model(model_name)
        output = infer(model, input_batch)

        return JSONResponse(content={"inference_output": output.tolist()})
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error processing image: {str(e)}")
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=str(e))

@app.post("/infer-url/")
async def infer_image_url(url: str = Form(...), model_name: str = Form(...)):
    try:
        if model_name not in MODEL_MAP:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Invalid model name provided.")

        response = requests.get(url)
        if response.status_code != 200:
            logger.error(f"Failed to download image from URL: {url}, Status code: {response.status_code}")
            raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Failed to download image from the provided URL.")

        image_bytes = response.content

        try:
            input_batch = preprocess_image(image_bytes)
        except UnidentifiedImageError:
            logger.error(f"The provided URL does not contain a valid image: {url}")
            raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="The provided URL does not contain a valid image.")

        model = load_model(model_name)
        output = infer(model, input_batch)

        return JSONResponse(content={"inference_output": output.tolist()})
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error processing image from URL: {url}, Error: {str(e)}")
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=str(e))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)


Dockerfile
FROM python:3.9-slim
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["uvicorn", "API:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", 8000"]

requirements.txt:
--extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu117
torch==2.0.0
torchvision==0.15.0
omegaconf
torchmetrics==0.10.3
fvcore
iopath
xformers==0.0.18
submitit
--extra-index-url https://pypi.nvidia.com
cuml-cu11
fastapi
Pillow
requests
uvicorn

Problem:
When I run the API locally, both endpoints work fine. However, when running the API in the Docker container, I get the following error:
{ "detail": "No operator found for memory_efficient_attention_forward with inputs:\n     query       : shape=(1, 257, 6, 64) (torch.float32)\n     key         : shape=(1, 257, 6, 64) (torch.float32)\n     value       : shape=(1, 257, 6, 64) (torch.float32)\n     attn_bias   : <class 'NoneType'>\n     p           : 0.0\ncutlassF is not supported because:\n    device=cpu (supported: {'cuda'})\nflshattF is not supported because:\n    device=cpu (supported: {'cuda'})\n    dtype=torch.float32 (supported: {torch.bfloat16, torch.float16})\ntritonflashattFis not supported because:\n    device=cpu (supported: {'cuda'})\n    dtype=torch.float32 (supported: {torch.bfloat16, torch.float16})\n    Operator wasn't built - seepython -m xformers.info for more info\n    triton is not available\nsmallkFis not supported because:\n    max(query.shape[-1] != value.shape[-1]) > 32\n    unsupported embed per head: 64" }
Additional Information:
The error seems to indicate that the CPU is not supported for the memory-efficient attention forward operator.
Locally, the API runs on a system with CUDA support.
In the Docker container, the application seems to be running on the CPU.
Question:
How can I resolve this error and make the API work correctly in the Docker container?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

The issue is resolved! I added the following line to my Dockerfile:
ENV XFORMERS_DISABLED=1
